# Symfony login via link into different firewall

Tags: symfony

I have two firewalls in my Symfony (5.4) application.

What I want is to create a login link for another firewall (where the login_link is configured) while **logged in into the other firewall**.
Currently the system doesn’t allow that (`No Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\LoginLink\LoginLinkHandler found for this firewall. Did you forget to add a "login_link" key under your "admin_area" firewall?`)

Is there a way to tell the login link creator to create the link for a specific firewall? (I didn’t see it in the implementation so I don’t really know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022-06-10**: Beginning with Symfony 6.1, just use the new Autowire-Attribute like this:

```
public function myLoginLinkAction(
    User $myUser,
    #[Autowire(service: 'security.authenticator.login_link_handler.my_other_firewall')] 
    LoginLinkHandlerInterface $myOtherFirewallLoginLinkHandler,
): Response {
    // …
    $loginLinkDetails = $myOtherFirewallLoginLinkHandler->createLoginLink($myUser);
    // …
}
```

For older Symfony versions:

The solution is to inject the concrete link handler service for my other firewall using an alias defined in `security.yaml` (where the other firewall that we want to build login links for is named "my_other_firewall"):

```
services:
    # define a concrete alias for the login link handler of the
    # my_other_firewall firewall to avoid the FirewallAwareLoginLinkHandler
    # that always uses the current request's firewall
    Symfony\Component\Security\Http\LoginLink\LoginLinkHandlerInterface $myOtherFirewallLoginLinkHandler: '@security.authenticator.login_link_handler.my_other_firewall'
```

Then, when I inject the `LoginLinkHandlerInterface` to my login link building controller, I use the defined parameter name `$myOtherFirewallLoginLinkHandler` and get the correct `LoginLinkHandler` injected instead of the `FirewallAwareLoginLinkHandler` that only exists to use the `LoginLinkHandler` defined for the firewall of the current request.

This solves the problem the documented way to use concrete implementations, when more than one implements a certain interface.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer. You should update the documentation page at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/edit/6.2/security/login_link.rst